# Defining Class Interface

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to define an interface for my Class. I've created some "input" and "output" public properties, that I'm assuming are the "gatekeepers". I've got a private sub within the Class that calculates variables. Can I not instantiate my class, set my input properties, and call on my output properties without have to call on the sub procedure. I've also tried calling on this sub within the Public Sub new but the properties still do not get set. The problem is that for my proper code I've got 8 or so inputs and 8 outputs so do I have to split all the sub procedures into each output and call these individually?

```
Public Class Class1

    Private m_inpHeight, m_inpHeight2 As Integer
    Private m_outHeight, m_outHeight2 As Integer


    Public Property Prp_inpHeight() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_inpHeight
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If m_inpHeight > 20 Then Exit Property
            m_inpHeight = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prp_inpHeight2() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_inpHeight2
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If m_inpHeight2 > 20 Then Exit Property
            m_inpHeight2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prp_OutHeight() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_outHeight
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prp_OutHeight2() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_outHeight2
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        AddTwoNumbers()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddTwoNumbers()
        m_outHeight = m_inpHeight + m_inpHeight2

        m_outHeight2 = m_inpHeight * 2

    End Sub

End Class
```

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Calc1 As Class1
        Calc1 = New Class1()

        Calc1.Prp_InpHeight = 10
        Calc1.Prp_InpHeight2 = 22

        MessageBox.Show(Calc1.Prp_OutHeight)
        MessageBox.Show(Calc1.Prp_OutHeight2)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You don't have an interface, just a class.

Comment: Just call `AddTwoNumbers` inside the property setters. Note also that VB has [ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/readonly) properties with only a getter and `WriteOnly` properties with only a setter.

Comment: thanks Oliver, that's working now

Comment: I've boiled down my properties to writeonly and readonly. But, if I call the sub procedure in each property and call each time I require that property am I not running that procedure each time... Its not sounding very efficient....   I just want to run it once and call each property individually.

Comment: You could add the input values as parameters to you constructor method then call it as something like Calc1 = New Class1(10, 22)